# Check whether the sum in a list is greater than 100

Tags: drools, drools-guvnor, drools-planner, drools-fusion, drools-flow

I have to write a drool function on a list which has to do the following thing

1. create a summation
2. check whether the summation is greater than 100.

below is the drool rule I have created

```
    rule "001"   
when 
       $charge : MainClass(subList.size() > 0)
       $item   : SubListClass(number < 0) from  $charge.subOrderROList
       $total  : Number() from accumulate(SubListClass( $p : number ),sum( $p ) 
then
       int index = $charge.SubListClass.indexOf($item)+1;
    violations.error(kcontext, "ad", "ad.message", new String[]{String.valueOf(index),$item.getNumber().toString()},index);
   end`
```

I am not able to check whether the $total is greater than 100

thanks

Answer (score 2):

This would be correct **if it were possible to obtain a sum > 100 by adding negative numbers**. I have kept the constraints as they were in the Q, so change this as appropriate. Maybe `number > 0`?

```
rule "001"   
when 
  $charge: MainClass(subList.size() > 0)
  $total: Number( intValue > 100 )
          from accumulate( SubListClass($p: number < 0)
                           from  $charge.subOrderROList,
                           sum( $p ) )
then
```